# .Net Realm.All<> returning empty list after connecting to Realm

Tags: .net, realm

The code below worked as intended for months. This is the second time now that for no apparent reason it has stopped returning data. Despite there being data in the realm database and the connection being established successfully all counts are 0 at the end. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

````
            IQueryable<ExampleRoute> AllRoutes = null;
            IQueryable<ExampleAsset> AllAssets = null;
            List<ExampleTestEvent> AllTestEvents = null;

            var credentials = Credentials.UsernamePassword("Redacted", "Example", false);
            var admin =  await Realms.Sync.User.LoginAsync(credentials, new Uri($"Realm URL"));
            var u = new Uri("Correct path.");
            var config = new QueryBasedSyncConfiguration(u, admin, "c:\\test.file");

            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
            {

                AllRoutes = realm.All<ExampleRoute>();
                AllAssets = realm.All<ExampleAsset>();
                AllTestEvents = realm.All<ExampleTestEvent>().ToList();

                int RouteCount = AllRoutes.Count();
                int AssetCount = AllAssets.Count();
                int TestCount = AllTestEvents.Count();
              }
    ```
````

Comment: does it throw an error? or just show 0 results?

Comment: No errors, just empty lists/0 results.

Comment: ever figure it out? running into this myself